# I cannot seem to obtain all data from a set?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I can't seem to be able to obtain all data that has been inserted into a set and display it appropriately, it displays the selected option in the next page like so:

Bean code:

```
public Object getItems() {
    return chosenLessons.entrySet().toArray();
}
public void addLesson(Lesson l) {
    Lesson i = new Lesson(l);
    this.chosenLessons.put(l.getId(), i);
```

Controller code:

```
 if (action.equals("/lessonTimetable")) {
        if (request.getParameter("btnSelect") != null) {
            this.selectedLesson = new LessonSelection(getID);
            lessons.ID = request.getParameter("lessonID");
            lessons.description = request.getParameter("lessonDescription");
            lessons.date = request.getParameter("lessonStartDate");
            lessons.startTime = request.getParameter("lessonStartTime");
            lessons.endTime = request.getParameter("lessonEndTime");
            lessons.level = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lessonLevel"));
            this.selectedLesson.addLesson(lessons);
            session.setAttribute("lessons", this.selectedLesson.getAll());
            //System.out.println(selectedLesson.getItems());
            //check for duplicate lessons
            rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/LessonSelectionView.jspx");
```

jstl code:

```
 <c:forEach var="getAll" items="${lessons}">
   <tr>
     <td>
       <c:out value="${getAll.value.description}"/>
     </td>
     <td>
       <c:out value="${getAll.value.date}"/>
     </td>
     <td>
       <c:out value="${getAll.value.startTime}"/>
     </td>
     <td>
       <c:out value="${getAll.value.endTime}"/>
     </td>
     <td>
       <c:out value="${getAll.value.level}"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
 <c:forEach
```

It displays one element row at a time not entire set which is what I want and when I do `system.out.println`, it adds and prints out everything that has been selected.

Comment: Where is the loop where you add all lessons to the object returned? It seems to me you are returning just an item indeed.

Comment: i thought foreach would do that to obtain all the contents of the set

Comment: `chosenLessons.put` is adding to a map, not a set, and `entrySet().toArray()` is going to give you an array of `Entry` objects; is that really what you want?

Comment: Is your lessons element even a list? It looks like only 1 lesson from what I see in controller code

Comment: well i get the same result when i just return the map

Comment: Oups my bad, just got confused by the naming you used... Btw you should be careful about the naming so you don't get confused yourself later when you get to review that code once again

Comment: Foreach will run through all elements you pur inside the var object returned to the interface. My point is that you added just an object. Then it's doing exactly what is expected, showing the single line you added. You must have a loop at the controller code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time controller execute you are initializing new LessonSelection(getID) and replacing this.selectedLesson. Then adding one lesson object to selectedLesson. That means all the time session will have only one object.

If you want to add new Lessons in to list and persist in session, you need to read previously added LessonSelection object from session using session.getAttribute("lessons") and then add new Lesson Object to the set then put it back in to session again

```
if (action.equals("/lessonTimetable")) {
    if (request.getParameter("btnSelect") != null) {
        // This code will make sure lessons are retrieved from session data 
        this.selectedLesson = session.setAttribute("lessons")  == null ? 
             new LessonSelection(getID):(LessonSelection)session.getAttribute("lessons") );
        //... Do all other operation you are doing 
        this.selectedLesson.addLesson(lessons);
        session.setAttribute("lessons", this.selectedLesson.getAll());
        //System.out.println(selectedLesson.getItems());
        //check for duplicate lessons
        rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/LessonSelectionView.jspx");

     }
 }
```

Comment: Additional, you should avoid declaring collections in your `Servlet`s in order to avoid multi threading issues.

Comment: Also, if the element is already in session, there's no need to register it again.

Comment: your missing a parameter in setAttribute?

Comment: i understood that but i get a null pointer exception on selectedLesson.getAll

Comment: Are you sure you assigning to this.selectedLesson  properly?